# Is there any easy way to find how many corners of a grid are inside a large circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polar-coordinates, computational-geometry

I'm trying to determine if there is a way to calculate the number of points, considered as intersections of a grid, and that either lie inside or on the circumference of a circle. The circle is centered on the origin and has radius R. I've defined the points as P={Px,Py} = {x1+Cw,y1+Dh} where C and D are any given pair of integers. Accordingly they should satisfy the equation

$(x1+Cw)^2+(y1+Dh)^2 <= R^2$

$x1$, $y1$, $w$, $h$, and $R$ are all constant.

I'm interested in approaches that give exact answer and are applicable to data sets like $R = 100,000$, $W=1$, $H$ = 1 implying at least a billion points. From a computational point of view I'd be interested in any ideas that could help speed up the process. Please note too I'm interested in exact solutions, not approximations.

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY This video might help

Comment: [Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) might be useful

Comment: I found another guy on Youtube finding this problem interesting, he suggests counting them column by column and take advantage of symmetry https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0KzBp75774&ab_channel=AnilKumar

Answer (score 2):

You may want to [read up about the Gauß circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the problem.  If so, please advise. 
Let $\lfloor r\rfloor$ denote the floor of $r$ 
(i.e. the largest integer $\leq r).$

I am assuming that the circle is of radius $R$ and centered at the origin
[i.e. centered at (0,0)].

Bypassing any attempt at elegance, I will calculate the grid points
on the positive portion of the $x$ axis, and then multiply that by 4.
By symmetry, that should give all grid points that are on the $x$ or $y$ axis,
except for the origin.  I will then add 1 for the grid point that represents the
origin.

Thus, this **first** computation is $T_1 = 1 + \left(4 \times \lfloor R \rfloor\right).$

Next, I will compute all the grid points that are in the **interior** of the
1st quadrant.  By symmetry, this computation will then be multiplied by 4 and
then (subsequently) added to the first computation.

Let $h$ go from 1 to $\lfloor R \rfloor,$ and 
let $f(h)$ denote the number of grid
points interior to the 1st quadrant when $y = h.$  
From the pythagorean theorem,
we have that

$f(h) = \lfloor \sqrt{(R^2 - h^2)}\rfloor.$

Thus the 2nd computation is 
$\displaystyle T_2 = 4 \times \left[\sum_{h = 1}^{\lfloor R \rfloor} f(h)\right].$

The final computation is $T_1 + T_2.$

Comment: Hi it's a good suggestion, I was kind of hoping for something better (i.e. a formula), but maybe it's not a trivial problem

Comment: @RobHoff Unless I've made a mistake in analysis, my computation gives the **exact** answer.  Assuming so, based on your comment, the issue is whether this answer can (somehow) be simplified.  Personally, I have no idea.

Comment: What I mean is, I'm just surprised all solutions seem to involve compututation that is dependent on the problem size, this is O(R) right, or sqrt(N)