# Points of square lattice inside a circle

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

**Background:** I'm reading a paper about Brownian Motion.

**Problem:** I have a square lattice of mesh size $\frac{1}{\lceil \epsilon^{-1} \rceil}$ where $\epsilon > 0$. Given a circle with radius $r$, how many points of the lattice are at most inside the circle?

**Solution:** The answer should be $2\epsilon^{-4}\pi r^2$ according to the paper.

**Thoughts:** In a square with length/height of $r$, there are at least $(\frac r \epsilon )^2$ many points of the lattice included. The area of a circle with radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$. Unfortunately, I have not had any better ideas.

Comment: Suppose that the mesh size is exactly $5$, and that $r \in \{3,4,5,6,7\}.$  Can you manually count the number of lattice points that are in each of the 5 circles?  Can you then form a hypothesis, based on the pattern that you have uncovered?  Can you then make an attempt to prove your hypothesis?  Can you edit your query to show in full detail, all of your thinking and work?  Please do **not** respond with a comment.

Comment: $\epsilon^{-4}$ looks wrong to me. I think it should be $\epsilon^{-2}$. The answer for a circle should be the same, up to constants, as for a square, and for a square you already know the answer has $\epsilon^{-2}$ in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see where your thought comes from. Do you have any proof-like argument for this though? That'd be a great help!

Comment: Is your query roughly the equivalent of [this mathSE query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825553/is-there-any-easy-way-to-find-how-many-corners-of-a-grid-are-inside-a-large-circ/3825661)?  Also, does [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) help?

Comment: It is the **Gauss circle problem** on which very good mathematicians have intevened. Probably where you have written ceil function you should do floor function.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I probably have to go with that. Thank you!

Comment: @Piquito Yes, that is what the comment above also suggested. However, the ceil function in my case is correct (assuming the author of the paper is correct).

Comment: Well, any circle is the inscribed circle of a square, and is the circumscribed circle of a square, and those two squares have a constant relation to each other – that ought to do it.